# Changing "name" of launcher for ios/android

Tags: react-native

I created my react native project with `react-native init runupdownnow`. That is short for "Run Up Down Now".

I now am ready to release my app to the stores. I was able to change the icon on android and ios. But I am not able to change the "name" that appear below the launcher icon. Is the only option to `react-native init "Run Up Down Now"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be changed by following the specifics for each platform - for Android inside the `ApplicationManifest.xml`, and in the application settings for iOS.

This isn't something that is controlled from within React Native - the init for the name is pre-setting these values, however can be changed as if they were native apps.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! May you please provide some specifics. In AndroidManifest.xml do I replace all instances of `@string/app_name` as in this screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/xQViOtk.png ?

Comment: And then for iOS is this screenshot correct, i had to dig around a bit to find it - http://i.imgur.com/EVVFdS4.png

Comment: For android, there is a strings.xml file (in the res folder somewhere) that has the reference - you can change that and it will propagate. 

That looks correct for iOS - the `flythru` project is the target that would be built. You should also change your package ID to something a bit more unique to your app (keeping the org...example stuff isn't great - try maybe just com.flythru or something).